# Django - Altering list view based on link that is pressed

Tags: django, django-views

I have a navbar above my products on my fake e commerce website that I am building. I render this view through list view. In this navbar I have a search area that works fine, and want to add the ability to filter the results based on what is pressed. For example, I have styles: realism, portrait, etc in the navbar. When I click on realism I want the results to change to all realism paintings that are in the DB.

My question is what would be the best way to accomplish this? Could I alter the original list view? Or would I just need to create an entirely new view based on the specific queries I need? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Also attached will be a picture to show you what I mean in case my explanation wasn't the best.

view:

```
class AllProductView(ListView):
    template_name = 'my_site/all_products.html'
    model = Product
    ordering=['id']
    paginate_by = 9
    context_object_name = 'products'
```

[image]

product model as requested:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    shortened_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_creation = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    history = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    style = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

Comment: Can you share your `Product` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added!

Comment: probably you wan to filter on the `style`?

Comment: yes you guessed correctly, thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by overriding the [**`.get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset):

```
class AllProductView(ListView):
    template_name = 'my_site/all_products.html'
    model = Product
    ordering=['id']
    paginate_by = 9
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        fltr = self.kwargs['style']
        if fltr != 'all':
            qs = qs.filter(style=self.kwargs['style'])
        return qs
```

In your urls.py, you can then use a `<str:…>` path converter to determine the style we want to filter on, so:

```
path('products/<str:style>/', AllProductView.as_view(), name='products')
```

In the templates, we can then write URLs with:

```
<a href="{% url 'products' style='realism' %}">Realism</a>
```

This will than link to a page that only shows `Product`s with `style='realism'`.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting way to accomplish this. I appreciate the help! I wasn't sure the best route to go in order to filter

Comment: I actually get a field error, specifically: Cannot resolve keyword 'genre' into field. Choices are: artist, artist_id, date_of_creation, discount_price, history, id, image, name, price, review, shoppingcartorderitem, shortened_name, slug, style

Comment: actually I fixed it, just a simple issue with trying to query for genre, when it is styles in my model:) thanks again!

Comment: @mharre: aarrgghhh... yes, somehow mixed it up, fixed now.

Comment: messing around with this solution for a bit I just realized that with this path in the url I can't render the url/products/all for example. Unless I am doing something wrong. But as far as my understanding in order for the allproductview to be called it needs a style right? Since I try to call the allproductview from my home page I also get a NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'all_products' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<style>[^/]+)/$']. I will continue trying to solve this on my own but was wondering if maybe you had any ideas about navigating this

Comment: ah has it turns out I can directly type the url/products/all, I am just not sure how to link to the all url haha

Comment: @mharre: with `{% 'products' style='all' %}`.

Comment: thanks again! My brain was dead after coding for about 8 hours and on my index page I still had genre instead of style haha